# Problem Installing Davinci Resolve 14.3

Tags: software-installation, scripts, 18.04

I am kind of new in Linux and I just downloaded Davinci Resolve installer which in .sh format. I tried to execute the .sh file using terminal (directing it to its directory) by using this command :

```
sudo ./DaVinci_Resolve_14.3_Linux.sh
```

and

```
sudo bash DaVinci_Resolve_14.3_Linux.sh
```

after some copyright text and pressing y to continue, it's somehow unable to create directories for the installment, resulting in this:

```
    Verifying archive integrity...  100%   All good.
Uncompressing DaVinci Resolve Installation Package  100%  
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/resolve’: No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/resolve/bin’: No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/resolve/configs’: No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/resolve/docs’: No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/resolve/easyDCP’: No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/resolve/graphics’: No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/resolve/logs’: No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/resolve/scripts’: No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/resolve/LUT’: No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/resolve/.LUT’: No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/resolve/.license’: No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/resolve/Fairlight’: No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/opt/resolve/Fairlight': No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/resolve/Media’: No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/opt/resolve/Media': No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/resolve/Resolve Disk Database’: No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/opt/resolve/Resolve Disk Database': No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/resolve/Cyclone’: No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/resolve/Cyclone/libs’: No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/resolve/Cyclone/plugins’: No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/resolve/Cyclone/Developer’: No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/resolve/Cyclone/LUT’: No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/resolve/Cyclone/UI_Resource’: No such file or directory
Extracting files...
cp: cannot create regular file '/opt/resolve/Cyclone': No such file or directory
./install.sh: line 42: Exit_With_Error: command not found
cp: cannot create regular file '/opt/resolve/Cyclone': No such file or directory
./install.sh: line 42: Exit_With_Error: command not found
cp: target '/opt/resolve/Cyclone/UI_Resource/.' is not a directory
./install.sh: line 42: Exit_With_Error: command not found
cp: target '/opt/resolve/Cyclone/libs/.' is not a directory
./install.sh: line 42: Exit_With_Error: command not found
cp: target '/opt/resolve/Cyclone/plugins/.' is not a directory
./install.sh: line 42: Exit_With_Error: command not found
cp: target '/opt/resolve/Cyclone/Developer/.' is not a directory
./install.sh: line 42: Exit_With_Error: command not found
cp: target '/opt/resolve/Cyclone/LUT/.' is not a directory
./install.sh: line 42: Exit_With_Error: command not found
cp: cannot create regular file '/opt/resolve/Cyclone': No such file or directory
./install.sh: line 42: Exit_With_Error: command not found
cp: cannot create regular file '/opt/resolve/Cyclone': No such file or directory
./install.sh: line 42: Exit_With_Error: command not found
cp: cannot create regular file '/opt/resolve/Cyclone': No such file or directory
./install.sh: line 42: Exit_With_Error: command not found
cp: cannot create regular file '/opt/resolve/Cyclone': No such file or directory
./install.sh: line 42: Exit_With_Error: command not found
cp: cannot create regular file '/opt/resolve/Cyclone': No such file or directory
./install.sh: line 42: Exit_With_Error: command not found
cp: cannot create regular file '/opt/resolve/Cyclone': No such file or directory
./install.sh: line 42: Exit_With_Error: command not found
cp: cannot create regular file '/opt/resolve/Cyclone': No such file or directory
./install.sh: line 42: Exit_With_Error: command not found
cp: cannot create regular file '/opt/resolve/Cyclone': No such file or directory
./install.sh: line 42: Exit_With_Error: command not found
cp: cannot create regular file '/opt/resolve/Cyclone': No such file or directory
./install.sh: line 42: Exit_With_Error: command not found
cp: cannot create regular file '/opt/resolve/Cyclone': No such file or directory
./install.sh: line 42: Exit_With_Error: command not found
cp: cannot create regular file '/opt/resolve/Cyclone': No such file or directory
./install.sh: line 42: Exit_With_Error: command not found
cp: cannot create regular file '/opt/resolve/Cyclone': No such file or directory
./install.sh: line 42: Exit_With_Error: command not found
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/resolve/Cyclone/Onboarding’: No such file or directory
cp: target '/opt/resolve/Cyclone/Onboarding/.' is not a directory
./install.sh: line 42: Exit_With_Error: command not found
tar: /opt/resolve/bin: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
./install.sh: line 49: Exit_With_Error: command not found
cp: cannot create regular file '/opt/resolve/bin': No such file or directory
./install.sh: line 42: Exit_With_Error: command not found
tar: /usr/lib64: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
./install.sh: line 49: Exit_With_Error: command not found
tar: /opt/resolve: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
./install.sh: line 49: Exit_With_Error: command not found
cp: cannot create directory '/opt/resolve': No such file or directory
./install.sh: line 42: Exit_With_Error: command not found
cp: cannot create regular file '/opt/resolve/Cyclone': No such file or directory
./install.sh: line 42: Exit_With_Error: command not found
cp: cannot create regular file '/opt/resolve/graphics/': No such file or directory
./install.sh: line 42: Exit_With_Error: command not found
cp: cannot create regular file '/opt/resolve/configs/config.dat': No such file or directory
./install.sh: line 42: Exit_With_Error: command not found
cp: cannot create regular file '/opt/resolve/configs/log-conf.xml': No such file or directory
./install.sh: line 42: Exit_With_Error: command not found
resolve: no process found
Copying Resolve files...
Copying scripts...
Copying docs...
Copying Onboarding package...
Copying Onboarding package...
Copying UI resources...
Copying libraries...
Creating shortcuts...
bmdpaneld: no process found
chmod: cannot access '/opt/resolve/configs': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/opt/resolve/easyDCP': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/opt/resolve/logs': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/opt/resolve/Developer': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/opt/resolve/LUT': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/opt/resolve/.LUT': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/opt/resolve/.license': No such file or directory
Resolve System Updated
```

and the installation failed.

Anyone can help me to solve this? As I quite need this app for my project.

Thank you.

Comment: I run one of them separately, both results the same.

Comment: Do you have an `/opt` directory? If not, create it (`sudo mkdir /opt`) and rerun your script.